# How to join tables by multiple columns for each id

Tags: r, join, grouping

I was forced to delete my previous topic because it wasn't well asked and the example was a little bit complex, so here it is with a simple one.

I have 2 dataframes :

```r
DF1<-data.frame(id1=c(1,1,1,1,1,2),client_code=c("x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x3"),id2=c("a","b","c","d","e","y"),value1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6),value2=c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6))

> DF1
  id1 client_code id2 value1 value2
1   1          x1   a    0.1    1.1
2   1          x1   b    0.2    1.2
3   1          x1   c    0.3    1.3
4   1          x2   d    0.4    1.4
5   1          x2   e    0.5    1.5
6   2          x3   y    0.6    1.6

DF2<-data.frame(id1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),id2=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","x","y"),value1=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),value2=c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27))

> DF2
  id1 id2 value1 value2
1   1   a     10     20
2   1   b     11     21
3   1   c     12     22
4   1   d     13     23
5   1   e     14     24
6   1   f     15     25
7   2   x     16     26
8   2   y     17     27
```

Each client belongs to a group of clients which is identified by column (id1)

What I'm trying to do is to add the missing rows from DF2 which their id2 are not present in DF1. This process should be done for each client (client_code) belonging to the same group of clients (id1) in DF1.

(I don't know if I made myself clear enough)

The desired output :

```r
output<-data.frame(id1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),client_code=c("x1","x1","x1","x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2","x2","x2","x2","x3","x3"),id2=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","d","e","a","b","c","f","y","x"),                  value1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,13,14,15,0.4,0.5,10,11,12,15,0.6,16),value2=c(1.1,1.2,1.3,23,24,25,1.4,1.5,20,21,22,25,1.6,26))

> output
   id1 client_code id2 value1 value2
1    1          x1   a    0.1    1.1
2    1          x1   b    0.2    1.2
3    1          x1   c    0.3    1.3
4    1          x1   d   13.0   23.0
5    1          x1   e   14.0   24.0
6    1          x1   f   15.0   25.0
7    1          x2   d    0.4    1.4
8    1          x2   e    0.5    1.5
9    1          x2   a   10.0   20.0
10   1          x2   b   11.0   21.0
11   1          x2   c   12.0   22.0
12   1          x2   f   15.0   25.0
13   2          x3   y    0.6    1.6
14   2          x3   x   16.0   26.0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Clearly this isn't clear. If you don't work to clearly say what you mean then you can't reason about, communicate about, search for or code what you want. Eg in "complete the missing rows from DF2", "missing" & "complete" are unexplained & the rows getting completed are not missing from D2. That's just a bunch of words that would appear in a clear specification. Moreover, guessing from what's given, this seems obviously a faq. PS When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create a table that shows for each client, what values of `id2` should
be present:

```r
library(tidyverse)

client_defaults <- df1 %>% 
  distinct(client_code, id1) %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = "id1")

client_defaults
#>    client_code id1 id2 value1 value2
#> 1           x1   1   a     10     20
#> 2           x1   1   b     11     21
#> 3           x1   1   c     12     22
#> 4           x1   1   d     13     23
#> 5           x1   1   e     14     24
#> 6           x1   1   f     15     25
#> 7           x2   1   a     10     20
#> 8           x2   1   b     11     21
#> 9           x2   1   c     12     22
#> 10          x2   1   d     13     23
#> 11          x2   1   e     14     24
#> 12          x2   1   f     15     25
#> 13          x3   2   x     16     26
#> 14          x3   2   y     17     27
```

Then, remove the rows that are already present in `df1`, and add the rest:

```r
client_missing <- client_defaults %>% 
  anti_join(df1, by = c("client_code", "id2"))

bind_rows(df1, client_missing) %>% arrange(client_code)
#>    client_code id1 id2 value1 value2
#> 1           x1   1   a    0.1    1.1
#> 2           x1   1   b    0.2    1.2
#> 3           x1   1   c    0.3    1.3
#> 4           x1   1   d   13.0   23.0
#> 5           x1   1   e   14.0   24.0
#> 6           x1   1   f   15.0   25.0
#> 7           x2   1   d    0.4    1.4
#> 8           x2   1   e    0.5    1.5
#> 9           x2   1   a   10.0   20.0
#> 10          x2   1   b   11.0   21.0
#> 11          x2   1   c   12.0   22.0
#> 12          x2   1   f   15.0   25.0
#> 13          x3   2   y    0.6    1.6
#> 14          x3   2   x   16.0   26.0
```

**Data:**

```r
df1 <- data.frame(client_code = c("x1", "x1", "x1", "x2", "x2", "x3"), id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), id2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "y"), value1 = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6), value2 = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), id2 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "x", "y"), value1 = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), value2 = c(20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible data.table solution, which is a bit more concise. Essentially it performs two steps:

1. Construct a completed data.table by joining `DF1` and `DF2` on each group in `id1` and `client_code`
2. Update the `value1` and `value2` columns by their appropriate `DF1` values

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(DF1); setDT(DF2)

DF <- DF1[, DF2[.BY, .SD, on = "id1", .SDcols = id2:value2], by = .(id1, client_code)]
DF[DF1, `:=`(value1 = i.value1, value2 = i.value2), on = c("id1", "client_code", "id2")]

DF
#>     id1 client_code id2 value1 value2
#>  1:   1          x1   a    0.1    1.1
#>  2:   1          x1   b    0.2    1.2
#>  3:   1          x1   c    0.3    1.3
#>  4:   1          x1   d   13.0   23.0
#>  5:   1          x1   e   14.0   24.0
#>  6:   1          x1   f   15.0   25.0
#>  7:   1          x2   a   10.0   20.0
#>  8:   1          x2   b   11.0   21.0
#>  9:   1          x2   c   12.0   22.0
#> 10:   1          x2   d    0.4    1.4
#> 11:   1          x2   e    0.5    1.5
#> 12:   1          x2   f   15.0   25.0
#> 13:   2          x3   x   16.0   26.0
#> 14:   2          x3   y    0.6    1.6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using a sql query.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf('
select  distinct
        a.id1
        , a.client_code
        , b.id2
        , coalesce(d.value1, e.value1) as value1
        , coalesce(d.value2, e.value2) as value2
from    df1 a
        left join df2 b
          on  a.id1 = b.id1
        left join df1 d
          on  a.id1 = d.id1
              and b.id2 = d.id2
              and a.client_code = d.client_code
        left join df2 e
          on  a.id1 = e.id1
              and b.id2 = e.id2
')

#    id1 client_code id2 value1 value2
# 1    1          x1   a    0.1    1.1
# 2    1          x1   b    0.2    1.2
# 3    1          x1   c    0.3    1.3
# 4    1          x1   d   13.0   23.0
# 5    1          x1   e   14.0   24.0
# 6    1          x1   f   15.0   25.0
# 7    1          x2   a   10.0   20.0
# 8    1          x2   b   11.0   21.0
# 9    1          x2   c   12.0   22.0
# 10   1          x2   d    0.4    1.4
# 11   1          x2   e    0.5    1.5
# 12   1          x2   f   15.0   25.0
# 13   2          x3   x   16.0   26.0
# 14   2          x3   y    0.6    1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to check each row in DF2.

We recreate your tables and make some of the columns as.character:

```
library(data.table)

DF1<-data.frame(id1=c(1,1,1,1,1,2),client_code=c("x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x3"),id2=c("a","b","c","d","e","y"),value1=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6),value2=c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6))
DF1$id2 <- as.character(DF1$id2)

DF2<-data.frame(id1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2),id2=c("a","b","c","d","e","f","x","y"),value1=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),value2=c(20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27))
DF2$id2 <- as.character(DF2$id2)
```

Then we save the column order of DF1 (will need this later)

```
column_order <- colnames(DF1)
```

And now we separate each client codes

```
client_codes <- as.character(unique(DF1$client_code))
```

And we define the New table that will contain the final results as a data frame

```
New_Table <- data.frame()
```

And now we create a nested for loop to take into account the different client codes and also check each row in DF2.

```
for(i in client_codes){
#So here we subset the DF1 data frame to only a certain client code  
New_DF1 <- DF1[DF1$client_code == i,]

temp_id <- unique(New_DF1$id1)
#and here we select the correct ids
New_DF2 <- DF2[DF2$id1 %in% temp_id,]

temp_df <- data.frame()
#And with this second for loop we perform a check on each of the new_DF2 rows
#to see if they have a matching client id
for(j in 1:nrow(New_DF2)){

  temp_row <- New_DF2[j,]
  if(nrow((New_DF1[New_DF1$id1 == temp_row$id1 & New_DF1$id2 == temp_row$id2,])) == 0){
    temp_row$client_code <- i
    setcolorder(temp_row, column_order)
    temp_df <- rbind(temp_df, temp_row)
  }

}

New_DF1 <- rbind(New_DF1, temp_df)

New_Table <- rbind(New_Table, New_DF1)

}
```